# Javascript \ Angular function help - mental block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, nested

I don't know what it is about JS, but I have a mental block. I apologize for the dumb question, but I'm at a loss because no matter how much I read I cannot get the academics into practice. Especially when it comes to nested functions.

I have a controller, lets say FileCtrl. Inside of it I have the the following that listens for file added to an input field via a directive. I'm attempting to inject an Angular JS factory service service called fileReader (a queue service for HTML5 FileReader).

However,I keep getting a undefined error on fileReader. I know why because, it cannot see fileReader, but injecting it at $scope.$on and then again on $scope.$apply doesn't work. Also, adding fileReader as a closure at the end of $scope.$on doesn't work either.

I should add that I can see the args.file and if I remove the fileReader code it will push the file no problem, but I then have no thumbnail. So I it works, just not with the fileReader and that is because Im doing something wrong with injection.

Side note, to Vals comment below I use apply as I found there was a image render sync issue without it which works fine for smaller images, but with larger images it freezes which is why I'm attempting to create and use a $q fileReader service. I suppose another way to solve for it would be to create a watch / directive on the array entry and when img comes back with the 64 encode string populate the html element ... like I said JS mental block :)

```
myApp.controller('FileController', ['$scope', 'FileReaderService',  function($scope, FileReaderService  ){  
    $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.progress = 0;
            fileReader.readAsDataUrl(args.file, $scope)
            .then(function(result) {
                $scope.imageSrc = result;
            });
            $scope.files.push(args.file);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share a bit from your `fileReader`, may be just declaration. Also have you included the `fileReader` script on your page?

Comment: Yeap, Nolan, all your module code is wanted =)

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS not all functions are been processed by Dependency Injection. In Controllers, Directives (in definition of directive and in controller, not on link or compile), Servicies AngularJS inject requested instances, but in some other functions (like event listeners) arguments are passed by position.

In your case you need to put `fileReader` into definition on controller, not on event listener.

Also you need to remove `apply` because event listeners added via `$on` are included into digest loop.

Comment: Val, I do have it in my controller, just did not add all that code for brevity sake. myApp.controller('FileController', ['$scope', 'fileReader',  function($scope, fileReader  ){

Comment: In updated code example I don't see `$on` so I can't see where you get `undefined error on fileReader`. I assume that you passed it into `$on` listener, so it get overwritten with `undefined` when listener is been called.

Comment: Val, sry I've out it back in. My question is how to I inject fileReader into the function. I've tried as a parameter and as closure. Neither work. It is really more of JS question so maybe my question is making this out to be more complex than it is.

Comment: If something is available on parent scope (I am talking about JS visibility scopes, not AngularJS), so it is available inside of inner scopes. 'closure' version should work perfectly. You don't need to pass reference to `fileReader` to inner listener function if it is available in controller's function. You can try to put it into plnkr.co so we can see+fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your replies. Val you made me go back and do a little more research and I found the answer with a little debugging. Not sure I understand why yet, but I have an idea.

1. If there is an error in your factory service, in my case, FileReaderService angular won't always explode when bootstrapping the service, will only explode when you call the service, which makes kind of makes sense. If something is wrong in the service the entire service will not boot. Also, you won't get any error message when injecting it into the controller. I had to place a watch on the module and noticed there was a reference error. I found I had a missing function.
2. Purely inexperience on my end, but I kept trying to capture the results form the $q service, which is was doing fine, but then attempting to inject to outside the $q return i.e. I was attempting to capture $scope.imageSrc = result and insert it post the .then, which doesn't work as you have a sync issue. I could see the value in the $scope.files, but it would not console.log or show up in HTML. So I moved all the file manipulation into the .then and it works perfectly. Logical when you think about it :) why have a $q if you not going to use it ... lol.

// problem code

```
fileReader.readAsDataUrl(args.file, $scope)
.then(function(result) {
    $scope.imageSrc = result;
});
// cannot and should not try to work the results outside the return promise 
$scope.files.imgSource = $scope.imageSrc;
$scope.files.push(args.file);
```

//Fixed and working code

```
myApp.controller('FileController', ['$scope', 'FileReaderService',  function($scope, FileReaderService  ){ 
    var reader;
    $scope.files = [];

    //listen for the file selected event
    $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
        $scope.progress = 0;
        var file = args.file;
        FileReaderService.readAsDataUrl(file, $scope)
            .then(function(result) {
                file.imgSource = result;
                $scope.files.push(file);
            });
    });
});
```